# How to set a command with semicolons to a variable in applescript

Tags: macos, variables, applescript

When I tries to set a command with semicolons to a variable, this error occurs: `expected "" but found unknown token`. The command is the following: `set md5Var to do shell script "find /Users/JS_Admin/Desktop/ -type f -exec cat {} \; | md5"`
.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
do shell script "find -type f '/Users/JS_Admin/Desktop/' -exec cat {} \\; | md5"
```